# Order of element and modulo?

Tags: group-theory

I'm viewing the proof for Fermat's little theorem [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat's_little_theorem#Proofs_using_group_theory)

and I'm confused about the part:

> Let $k$ be the order of $a$, that is, $k$ is the smallest positive integer such that $a^k ≡ 1 \pmod p$.

Why is there a modulo?

Comment: That question - your last sentence - is quite unclear. Can you be more specific. That is the definition of the order of an element.

Comment: I thought the order of element meant smallest $k$ s.t. $a^k=e$, $e$ being the identity element. Why is there the modulo?

Comment: That's the order of an element of a group, but the integers are not a group under multiplication. There is a sense in which this is the order in a group, but if you haven't discussed the multiplicative group of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, better to take this as a definition of "order modulo $p$."

Comment: If we view ourselves as working in the multiplicative group of units, we do not need "modulo." But usually in beginning number theory one avoids explicit group-theoretic language.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of order given  coincides with the definition of order for an element of a group recalled in the comment when one considers $a$ as an element of the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$.